# Ошибка Cannot access protected property в nginx

Tags: nginx, php

Здравствуйте. Раньше пользовался `apache` - всё работало. Теперь установил `nginx` и все методы и атрибуты, отмеченные как `protected`, не работают. Выдаёт ошибку:

> Cannot access protected property.

Не подскажите, в чём может быть проблема.. Может, какие настройки `php` или ещё что...

Comment: С уверенностью могу сказать одно - nginx тут точно не при чем. Отлаживайте свой PHP скрипт, смотрите что где подключается и вызывается и учитесь пользоваться [пошаговым отладчиком](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote).

Answer (score 1):

У меня так было, когда я ставил nginx + eAccelerator + php-fpm.

Ошибка тогда была в eAccelerator, если она у вас стоит, посмотрите какая у вас версия и погуглите.